# Cloud run console how to use container command and command arguments fields

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

So we are trying to deploy our containerized service to Google Cloud Run. Here is a docker compose describing out service. This compose works.

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  core_api:
    build: .
    image: core:core
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=application.py
      - APP_SETTINGS=config.TestingConfig
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis/0
      - CELERY_BACKEND_URL=redis://redis/0
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: uwsgi --http :8080 --module application:application --enable-threads
```

As you can see this is your standard flask microservice.
Here is our cloud run console:

[image: cloud run config]

Unfortunately, we keep getting errors like the following:

```
uwsgi: unrecognized option '--http :8080'
```

We've tried a variety of approaches including putting everything in the command. All similar errors. Does anyone understand how to translate this?

Comment: did you try `--http=:8080` ? If it works, it should fail on module arg. Use again the equal sign, it should solve your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was to separate the parameters by whitespace.

So instead of `--http :8080` it's two parameters `--http` `:8080`